# ¿Como puedo consultar los correos que tengan una fecha mayor a 30 dias de la fecha indicada en la base de datos con Mysql y php?

Tags: php, mysql

disculpen estoy atascado con una consulta, mi tabla se llama altaproveedor, y tengo muchos campos, entre ellos: email_repre y fecha_positiva.

lo que estoy intentando hacer es consultar y seleccionar todos los correos de email_repre cuando la fecha_positiva sea mayor a 30 días de la fecha indicada ahí y la fecha actual (la idea es mandar un email masivo con php a todos esos correos con fecha mayor a 30 días),

tengo la noción de hacer la diferencia de fecha entre la fecha indicada ahí en fecha_positiva y la fecha actual del servidor. si es mayor a 30 dias (o mas) que me seleccione los emails y tengo entendido que se hace con DATEDIFF pero no se como implementarlo con el where. el campo de correo es varchar y la fecha date, gracias por la ayuda. [image: columna de los campos email y date]

este es mi codigo:

SELECT email_repre, (DATEDIFF(now(),fecha_positiva)) as dias FROM altaproveedor;

funciona a la perfección, pero no se como hacer que me seleccione los emails con mas de 30 días

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado al momento?, agregalo por favor

Comment: Recuerda que puedes editar tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario y añadir la info relevante (en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta). La opción editar está justo bajo la pregunta y las etiquetas!
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Listo, ya resolví yo mismo mi duda, muchas gracias a todos por su importante ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta utilizando [`DATE_SUB`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_sub.asp) que te permite restarle dias/mes/años a una fecha. En tu caso solo restale 30 dias a la fecha actual:

```
SELECT email_repre, (DATEDIFF(now(),fecha_positiva)) as dias FROM altaproveedor
WHERE DATE_SUB(getdate() INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo. ya lo resolví hace unos segundos, gracias de verdad :)